# Move directories Excluding file

Tags: linux, shell

I have 40 directories and 1 shell.sh file in directory. I want to move all directories to other directory excluding shell.sh file. Just 40 directory move to other directory and shell.sh don't move its remain as same directory. Is there is any solution ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to mentioned directory and run in terminal:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 ! -path . -type d -exec mv '{}' destination_path \;
```

This will also work with directories with spaces in name